# I need example of correct using of comint and getting last comand output

Tags: comint

I had a problem with execution of `(comint-simple-send process command)`. My previous example would not show the last output because I didn't use the hook and the result was being dispalyed before the command finished it's execution. Als I didn't know about having to restart the process to reflect the code changes.

### My solution

The following code works.

```
(add-hook 'comint-output-filter-functions
          '(lambda (txt) (message (format  " output ----------- %c%s" 10 txt))))

(let* ((process-buffer (make-comint-in-buffer "StrangeTerm" "*strange-term*" "/bin/bash"))
       (p (get-buffer-process process-buffer)))
  (comint-simple-send p "ls -l /"))
```

The lambda has the expected output, which I can see in *Messages* and in future I can do what I want with it.

Please confirm if this is the correct approach.

Comment: Why do you use `ansi-term` for `ls ~/Desktop`? Can't you use `directory-files` or `shell-command` or `async-shell-command`? (The latter two if the `ls ~/Desktop` is just an example of what you want to do.)

Comment: it could be any command, like asking a programming language interpreter for the list of loaded modules.

Comment: You can call arbitrary commands from elisp without sending them to an ansi-term process. Unless you need to run multiple commands in the same terminal, there is an easier way to get the output of any single command.

Comment: I know there are easier ways, but to understand comint-mode and talking to processes i need to do it this way.

Comment: Note that `term-mode` is based on comint but it does not use it.

Comment: Note that you don't need a `strange-term`. Just use text properties to identify boundaries (`put-text-property` is your friend). You can even put text properties on newline characters.

Answer (score 3):

One crude non-robust way to get the last output in `term-mode`is:

```el
(defun term-recommended-hook ()
  "Hook function recommended as `term-mode-hook'. (See file \"term.el\".)"
  (setq term-prompt-regexp "^[^#$%>\n]*[#$%>] *")
  (setq-local mouse-yank-at-point t)
  (setq-local transient-mark-mode nil)
  (auto-fill-mode -1)
  (setq tab-width 8 ))

(add-hook #'term-mode-hook #'term-recommended-hook)

(let ((p (get-buffer-process "*ansi-term*")))
  (comint-simple-send p "ls ~/Desktop")
  (with-current-buffer (get-buffer "*ansi-term*")
    (buffer-substring-no-properties (save-excursion (term-previous-prompt 1) (forward-line) (point)) (line-beginning-position))))
```

Comment: thank you, I get what I want except the fact that buffer substring returns only last line of output. I think I can manage from this point onwards.

Comment: @ruby_object In that case you didn't probably run `term-recommended-hook` (the setting for `term-prompt-regexp` is most important). Note that after installing the hook you need to restart `ansi-term`.

Comment: killing the term process, as you said and your hook example has helped me to find the solution.